# Keyboard Shortcut for Keytext

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

My job involves copying data from the web to a database. To improve efficiency we are working on a keyboard shortcut using Keytext, to save a copied article, and open the page for posting the new article using a single key. This involves clicking the "save" button, and wait for some time for the database to save the article, and then clicking on the "new content" button. I have figured out the keys to do this, but I need a key to wait for the time in which the article gets saved. Is there a key which instructs the computer to wait and do nothing for a while?